# Create Analog of odometr in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm making a car race game, there I have to measure the distance using adometr, it should look like in real car, like this:

[image]

Numbers should change each other as in old cars. If I had a closed area out of this object, I would have used mask, but in my case I don't have any closed area, I can't put my number under its window, how is it possible to create such thing?

Comment: Have a look at SKCropNode

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I thought about it. I could crop this squares from my object, but I can't put my numbers under their window, I have no place there(

Comment: The numbers would be a long "strip" -  01234567890 with the mask only revealing one number at a time. As you move the strip up you move the mask down so the revealed number stays in a fixed location in the screen. When you display the 0 after 9 you quickly change the offsets back so that the first 0 is displayed and you are ready to go again.  Repeat this strip for each digit in the odometer